# Collapsing grids with twitter bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a 1 row 4 col grid. How do I collapse it like this.

**Large**
1 Row 4 columns

**Medium**
2 rows 2 columns

**Small**
2 rows 2 columns

**Xtra Small**
4 rows 1 column

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this..

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">x</div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">x</div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">x</div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">x</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this case, you only need to specify `col-sm-*` since sm and md are the same layout, and the grid will automatically stack into a single col on smallest devices (xs).

Demo: http://bootply.com/86156

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much. Will that sample url be permanent or does it expire?

Comment: Can i assume col-xs defaults to 1 column, and rows = how many divs you have in there?