# make a modal with form inputs on same line, length, and white space? (pic example provided)

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, stripe-payments

Been trying for a few hours meow, (really need to get better at html) but all I want is essentially 3 inputs on a modal, with `form-control` would be nice cause I like the appearance but doesn't have to be at this point, on a bootstrap modal for payment.

Here is what I'm trying to get

[image: Pulled from Stripe Checkout]

I know right, you think I'd be able to get this

```
<div class="modal-body text-center form-horizontal" id="modal_body">
                    <form action="/made_payment" method="POST" id="payment-form">
                    <span class="payment-errors"></span>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" size="20" data-stripe="number" placeholder="Card Number">
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12" style="display: inline-flex;">
                            <data class="col-xs-6">
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" size="4" data-stripe="exp_month" placeholder="Exp (MM/YY)">
                            </data>
                            <data class="col-xs-6">
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" size="4" data-stripe="cvc" placeholder="CVC">
                            </data>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                </div>
```

Comment: It might help to include the code you've tried so we can see what's going wrong.

Comment: i've been all over the place but I'll edit with what I had last

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First your html structure need reorganising *unless it was intentional*. Based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19232615/collapsing-grids-with-twitter-bootstrap-3) - create a no-gutter class and apply to the row where you want to remove the spacing(gutter) between the columns - (*I have replaced the data tags with divs for readability*) :

```css
.no-gutter {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;    
}

.no-gutter > [class^="col-"] {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="modal-body text-center form-horizontal" id="modal_body">
  <form action="/made_payment" method="POST" id="payment-form">
    <span class="payment-errors"></span>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group no-gutter col-xs-6">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" data-stripe="number" placeholder="Card Number">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" size="4" data-stripe="exp_month" placeholder="Exp (MM/YY)">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" size="4" data-stripe="cvc" placeholder="CVC">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

*As for the rest of the styling that's up to your css and bootstrap* [check this out bootstrap input groups](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups) - Good luck